# Does C++ offer support for an asynchronous approach?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I would like to make my application more responsive, more snappy, I'm interested in an asynchronous approach but from what I know C++ does not support asynchronous approaches of any kind: is this true?

EDIT:
I will appreciate having some names of good libraries about this.

Comment: True. Use third-party libraries.

Comment: you should mention the GUI toolkit you use

Comment: Graphical Uer Interface, toolkit can be Qt, Gtk, WxWidgets, etc.

Comment: You can do almost anything you want in C++. To get a better answer maybe you should say _what_ you want to do asynchronously?

Comment: @Sergey can you suggest some ?

Comment: @CharlesB i'm not talking about GUIs, just generic tasks

Comment: You mean asynchronous callback or threading?

Comment: @axis If you're not referring to a GUI application, what kind of application are we talking about? What are your goals about responsivity and snappiness enhancments. Usually you would use a library that supports multi-threading like boost asio. If you dislike boost for some reason you may have a look at the Platinum C++ Framework: http://www.pt-framework.org/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true, but not completely: while C++ the language does not have asyncronous mechanisms itself, one can build an asyncronous layer as a library on top of the language, for example. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/design/async.html

If you want threads, C++11 provides native support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Threading_facilities

Boost uses template metaprogramming heavily, so be ready to some hardcore metaprogramming.

Comment: Just because *some* parts of Boost *internally use* TMP doesn't necessarily mean you're ever exposed to TMP yourself. Actually, the only places you should really come in touch with TMP are the Boost libraries that are build around that feature, like MPL and Fusion.

Comment: Boost libraries again, i know this libraries, what I really don't like about this libraries are the Docs and the building system that is horrible to me. Threads is what i would like to avoid. I suppose that the only real options are the Boost libs.

Comment: @axis If you want to avoid thread the only other option is separate processes with some kind of interprocess communication, which is a much bigger hassle. It can be wrapped just like threads and inter-thread communication primitives like in Boost or C++11. And that's leads to another thing about your question, that even so called asynchronous languages just wraps what's in the underlying operating system, they just provide these wrappers for you in a nice way. The difference with C++ is that up until now you had to make those wrappers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++11 has low-level building blocks for multithreading and concurrency (`<thread>`), aswell as higher-level abstractions for task-level parallelism and asynchronicity (`<future>`, including `std::async` to launch asynchronous tasks).

For a more general approach to asynchronous operations that doesn't necessarily involve threads, I'd recommend taking a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/).

Comment: C++11 is not very well supported at the moment, especially on mobile devices, and is a really young standard.

Comment: @axis: On mobile, I wouldn't know, but with GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.1 I wouldn't call it "not very well supported". Even Visual Studio 2012 has (and 2010 had) a good part of C++11 implemented. Especially `<future>` and `<thread>` are widely supported. Also, does it matter that it's a "young" standard? Most compilers started implementing C++11 features as soon as the standard committee added them to their working paper and when it was still called C++0x in hope for a <2010 ratification.